# Why doesn't List.BinarySearch() have overloads that take Comparison<T> in addition to IComparer<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, binary-search, icomparer

I want to use `List.BinarySearch()` with a custom item type. The custom type does not implement `IComparable<T>`; instead I have several static `Comparison<T>` functions that I call because at various points I want to sort the list on different criteria. Plus I think it adds clarity since the way you are sorting can be described by the function name. Now I want to do a binary search on the list. I wanted to use one of my comparison functions, only to find that `List.BinarySearch()` doesn't have an overload that accepts `Comparison<T>`, only `IComparer<T>`. I try to avoid `IComparer<T>` because it seems silly to me to have a separate class just for comparing objects. Why doesn't `List.BinarySearch()` have overloads that take `Comparison<T>` in addition to `IComparer<T>`? And is there any way to use my existing `Comparison<T>` functions in `List.BinarySearch()`?

Comment: where is the code that you are using to do the search a foreach or for loop..??

Comment: Create a comparer that delegates to your comparison. Good to go.

Comment: Can anybody answer my first question: why doesn't List.BinarySearch() have overloads that take Comparison<T> in addition to just IComparer<T>? Just out of curiosity...

Comment: It's an omission, we should report the bug to Microsoft.

Comment: Please vote for the bug report at https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/2188

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very easy to create an `IComparer<T>` from a `Comparison<T>` - here's a (slightly amended) class from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) which you're welcome to use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Utility to build an IComparer implementation from a Comparison delegate,
/// and a static method to do the reverse.
/// </summary>
public class ComparisonComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> comparison;

    public ComparisonComparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        if (comparison == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        }
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```

You could also add an extension method to `List<T>` to do this for you:

```
public static int BinarySearch<T>(this List<T> list, Comparison<T> comparison)
{
    return list.BinarySearch(new ComparisonComparer(comparison));
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best solution, although I'm not overly fond of it. I am still very curious about why the overloads don't exist to use Comparison<T> directly.

Comment: @Craig: As ever, there's a cost to introducing anything. I suspect that the BCL maintainers feel it doesn't quite make the bar of utility against cost.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I don't see why that would be, since there's an equivalent overload for `.Sort()` that does use `Comparison<T>`.  I think they just overlooked it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: It may well not have been the same person making the decision for both methods, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Create wrapper for `Comparison` such as this one:

```
public class ComparisonWrapper<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private Comparison<T> comparison;
    public ComparisonWrapper(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension on Jon's answer that takes a lambda expression.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int BinarySearch<T>(this List<T> list, T item, Func<T, T, int> compare)
    {
        return list.BinarySearch(item, new ComparisonComparer<T>(compare));
    }
}

public class ComparisonComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> comparison;

    public ComparisonComparer(Func<T, T, int> compare)
    {
        if (compare == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparison");
        }
        comparison = new Comparison<T>(compare);
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        return comparison(x, y);
    }
}
```